# Intercepting proxies and web traffic interception

Tags: proxy

What are intercepting proxies? How can you intercept web traffic and what are the tools for it?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, even though it was downvoted and closed by admins. At the time of writing it has 3557 views and 2 answers that are very useful. Your work is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Intercepting proxies are tools used to analyze, modify, and in some cases inject traffic into the normal session created between a client and server.**

One common example where this is used is in testing the security of a website using a tool like [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp/) which acts as a proxy connecting your own web-browser to it, frequently using a plugin similar to [foxyproxy](https://getfoxyproxy.org/) but this can also be done via manual configuration, then having Burp Suite initiate connections to the web server on the clients behalf.

This allows Burp Suite to control a connection that was requested by the web browser and allows for a large number of tools and testing methodologies to be inserted into the connection. It should be noted that there are some browser plugins which can perform many security tests but by utilizing the hooks to connect to a proxy it removes many of the software limitations and allows for much easier testing of the web server.

Finally it's worth mentioning that these allow for dynamic testing of the application which is very different than what you might do by simply analyzing traffic between the client and server. Likewise there are lots of other types of intercepting proxies used for other types of testing (not just for security).

Comment: Fiddler is another alternative. You can find it here: https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Answer (score 1):

Intercept proxies are machines which intercept your packets and request certain service on behalf of you .

Web traffic interception is way in which some middle device intercept your http header and payload whatever the purpose of doing so

Example is squid and at higher end it is burp suite also